# Add a UITextField that retains its text in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

How do I achieve a UITableViewCell with a textField in it? Ive been through a few similar questions on StackOverflow, but I find most of them deal with cases where the tableView's display is always constant and the know exactly what values go where. For my implementation the number of section and number of rows per section are determined by the user and could be anything. I have been able to get a textField in the cell but I find any text entered is lost when I scroll the table and the cell disappears from view. This is what i have so far

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc]
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(215, (cell.contentView.bounds.size.height-30)/2, 60, 30)];

    [myTextField setDelegate: self];
    myTextField.tag = indexPath.section;
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)myTextField.tag);


    myTextField.placeholder = @"0%";
    myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    [cell addSubview:myTextField];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.cellLabels[indexPath.section];
    return cell;
}
```

I know what the problem is, I just cant figure out a work around. Even if I store everything the user enters in each textField in an array somehow, I cant set the text for each field when it return from being off screen as the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called again and the textField is redrawn.

This is pretty much what I want, functionality wise. But "Paper1" and "Paper2" may be different sections...

[image: This is pretty much what I want]

Answer (score 1):

Use a view model. Store the text for each cell in an array and then set the text in cellForRowAtIndexpath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc]
                      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(215, (cell.contentView.bounds.size.height-30)/2, 60, 30)];

    [myTextField setDelegate: self];
    myTextField.tag = indexPath.section;
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)myTextField.tag);

   myTextField.placeholder = @"0%";
   myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    myTextField.text = [self textForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell addSubview:myTextField];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.cellLabels[indexPath.section];
    return cell;
```

}

Comment: Part of the problem is the text is decided by the user, I cant predict their input and store in an array.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you predict their input. You need to store the text they've entered. You've set the delegate for some reason you haven't shared. Now you just need to record the text in your view model as it's entered.

Comment: Basically, don't use the text fields as your primary text storage.  Use a view model (array of strings or perhaps "Papers"?).

Comment: Got you, will try this